# How to get an element's int value from a String matrix?

Tags: java

I would like to get an element's int value from a String matrix.

My task is to implement the easiest version of Uniqual (https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/unequal.html) with some kind of tree or graph search algorithm.

That's why I thought of implementing the table as a string, as it can contain both characters and digits.

I have already tried this method: 
Character.isDigit(matrix[i].charAt(j))
for my issue. I guess it's not the correct way to do so.
Maybe if I get the element's char value, I could implement a simple function that checks whether it is a number or a digit or special char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for -

```
char c = matrix[i].charAt(j);
int cVal = Character.getNumericValue(c);
```

I am preferring this method because if `c='1', cVal = 1`.

Comment: I have up voted your answer, but please clean up (remove the 'a' in numerica) Character.getNumericaValue

Comment: Thanks for the quick response for both of you. 
Now i realized that my problem in both cases is when I try to use char.At method on a matrix, I get "cannot resolve method 'char.At(int)'" error.
The matrix is declared as String. It works on a simple String tho.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`Character.isDigit(matrix[i].charAt(j))` just tells you if the character is a digit character. To get the value from the character, simply subtract 0's character value

```
int val = (int) (matrix[i].charAt(j) - (int)'0');
```